# Different memory usage with macOS app between an M1 and Intel MacBook Pro

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, instruments

I have an x86_64 macOS app that according to Activity Monitor, it uses between 35 to 50MB of memory with an Intel MacBook Pro. When I run the same app in an M1 MacBook Pro with Rosetta, it shows 2.5 to 3x more memory in Activity Monitor.

I then updated the app in my M1 to both x86_64 and arm64, and run it again. In the Intel MacBook Pro it uses 40 to 60MB in Activity Monitor. In the M1, Xcode still shows the 3x increase in Memory Report and Activity Monitor.

In the M1, from Memory Report I clicked Profile in Instruments and it shows the heaviest stack trace is in system libraries, specifically this one:

*46 AppKit  183.46 MB     +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:]*

See the image and the call tree all the way down to **mmap**:

[image]

However, when I try to profile the app again in my M1 but directly from Instruments > Allocations, it shows the regular 35-50MB memory usage, nothing more. *[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:]* is not taking all the memory as above. Here is an image:

[image]

The only graphics the app has are a couple of storyboards with some custom Core Graphics code for custom drawings. I'm on Big Sur 11.2 and Xcode 12.4.

My understanding of memory usage using Instruments is basic, so my questions are:

1. What could be happening here with the different memory usage between M1 vs Intel, and between Instruments and Instruments running from Memory Report?
2. Why is all the memory going to this NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:]?
3. How can I reduce the memory usage for the M1?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried comparing how builtin apps fare under roseta? It might just be that rosetta apps have a memory overhead in general

Comment: Thanks. My app is running native (arm64) in the M1. Built in apps like Finder, Calculator, etc. also run native and use kind the same memory with the Intel, except Notes and Calendar; this last one shows almost double in the M1. 

I have other third party apps in the M1 running in Rosetta that indeed run with 2x more memory. I have one running native and has the same memory with the Intel. I could understand the Rosetta translation is causing the memory overhead, but my app is arm64. I would like to know why and if that could be fixed.

Comment: @RobMoj I have the exact same issue, as per the activity monitor data, the app running on the intel machine utilises about 60MB of memory but the same app on M1 uses 300 MB?! Did you manage to solve this problem? Any advice is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @iBuilt Hi. I didn't solved the problem. I don't know if it was another Xcode or macOS update, but the issue was fixed by itself after Big Sur 11.2 and Xcode 12.4. Now, there's no increase in memory usage between Intel and Apple Silicon; it's the same. Don't know why. I no longer have a workstation to test it again with Big Sur 11.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how much memory your app is using, look at the Persistent Bytes column for the All Heap Allocations category in the Allocations instrument. Note that this category does not include texture memory.

To make it easier to find the code that allocates the most memory, click the Call Tree button at the bottom of the Instruments window and select the Invert Call Tree and Hide System Libraries checkboxes. The following tutorial provides a detailed explanation on using Instruments to measure memory usage:

[Measuring Your App's Memory Usage with Instruments](https://www.swiftdevjournal.com/measuring-your-apps-memory-usage-with-instruments/)

Comment: Thank for the response. I read that tutorial before posting the question and followed the steps. I didn't click Hide System Libraries because when I did, the 80% of the memory (220MB) appears under main but there's not a > to click and see what's inside. Only by not clicking Hide System Libraries is that I can see where is all that memory. The system libraries are taking the big chunk but only in the M1 MacBook Pro and in Instruments run from Memory Report

Comment: Don't worry about the main listing. You have no control over it. I doubt your app is using 183 megabytes of memory loading the nib file because your second screenshot shows 2.25 megabytes of memory for loading the nib file.

Comment: I understand but the macOS Activity Monitor shows ~190MB of memory usage when the app is running (standalone, not from Xcode) in the M1. It shows only 50MB in the Intel. Isn't that the real memory used and why so much difference? The 2.25MB nib file in the second screenshot is running through Instruments > Allocations directly. The first screenshot shows the same nib file with 183MB but through Memory Report > Profile in Instruments.  I'm trying to understand why is the big difference since the app was ported to universal binary.

Comment: The Activity Monitor instrument most likely includes the virtual memory reserved for the app, the equivalent of the All Heap and Anonymous VM category in the Allocations instrument. The information from the Allocations instrument is going to be more accurate. I don't know why the Activity Monitor instrument is reporting 3-4 times the amount of memory usage on the M1 than on Intel.